# OSX 10.13 Allow/remove from blocked system software via Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, gatekeeper, serveradmin

I am running a Mac mini in a datacenter 5000 km from my location and I am using Remote Desktop to run and manage it. When I installed Google Drive File Stream it stopped working and I got the advice that I need to allow it run.

[image]

But nothing happens when I click "Allow". Somebody told me it was because I use Remote Desktop (same with TeamViewer).

I wonder if there is a workaround for this or another way to install Google Drive File stream. 10.13.3 Beta on Apple Mac mini and Little Snitch installed.

Real problem
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the screenshot you mentioned?

Comment: Done :) . it seem there is protection of some functions over remote desktop.